# Java Web EE where to place SQLite database files

Tags: java, database, sqlite, web, netbeans

I'm using Netbeans to create a java web EE project but i'm having trouble connecting my database. I have created a class which connects my database.
When I test the class it can connect and search the database just fine but when I build and run the project it cannot seem to connect to the database.

I have tried copying and pasting the database into the build folders but it still cannot connect to my database.

Please help and thank you for taking the time to look at my question

Comment: The database jar should be in your WEB-INF/lib directory

Comment: I'm not talking about the database jar, I'm talking about the file that contains the database

Comment: connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:D:/idea-workspace/SqlLite/sqlite/testDB.db");

Comment: That code is in my class, I'm talking about where to put the database in the file

Comment: This is the file path to your database D:/idea-workspace/S‌​qlLite/sqlite/testDB‌​.db location make it the complete to where your .db file is

Comment: Yes I have used the path to my database. When I test my class it works but when it is build and run as a project it fails to find my tables

Comment: Whats the stack error